# Remove null bytes from file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, binary-files

How to remove leading null bytes in a binary file on Win CMD?
This file could be the result of file splitting or truncation where null bytes were indicators of file boundaries in the (larger) parent file.

Comment: Typically I would recommend an hex editor like HxD for such a job. Windows does not include tools for binary manipulations on GUI or cmd level.

Comment: binary files on Win cmd can be edited with a few built-in cmd commands & bundled utilities like `fc`, `comp`, `certutil`, `Debug`, `copy`, `fsutil` & `forfiles`. Some text commands also have limited binary edit potential (beyond printable characters), like `more`, `set` & `type`.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way would be to use a hex editor like the free
[HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

This (untested) PowerShell script will also do it:

```
$file = "C:\path\to\file"
$Bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
$i = 0
While ($i < $Bytes.Length -and $Bytes[$i] -eq 0) { $i++ }
$Bytes = $Bytes[$i..($Bytes.Length-1)]
[IO.File]::writeAllBytes($file, $bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike EOF, there's no beginning of file indicator available to batch scripts on Win CMD, which doesn't have direct access to MFT or FAT. The first few bytes of file can be accessed by reading the file itself, or truncated to (keep) only the first part of the file with `fsutil`.

There's no utility or command to keep/extract the latter part of the file in CMD. A workaround would be to hex dump, remove the redundant bytes, then `certutil` or `forfiles` the remainder back to the required binary file.

A powershell solution to extract 2nd part of file (without leading redundant bytes/nulls):

```
powershell gc <file> -Encoding byte -Tail <size> ^| sc <out> -Encoding byte
```